# java.lang.NumberFormatException For Input String value is letters

Tags: java, jframe, jtextfield

This is the Code and when i input a letter it would not display the line .matches instead i got an error but if i remove the parseFloat rec1 and remove the else if (rec1 < total) then the .matches line will display please help me how to do this thank you in advance

CashType c = new CashType();
        c.setVisible(true);

```
    c.jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
         String receive = c.jTextField1.getText();


         float total = total("sellno"+SellNoCount.getText());
         float rec1 = Float.parseFloat(receive); //this is line 1525

            if(!receive.matches("[0-9]+")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter a Valid Amount");
                c.jTextField1.setText("");

            }

            else if(receive.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter Amount");
            }
            else if(rec1 < total){

              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Insufficient Amount");

            }
```

//ERROR

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "asdasd"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
at projectfinal.SellPage$32.actionPerformed(SellPage.java:1525)
```

Comment: You need to check if it matches before you try parsing.

Comment: And you need to check if it's empty before you check if it matches.

Comment: Check this condition before parsing the value `if(!receive.matches("[0-9]+"))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message, it look like you are entering "asdasd" to jTextField1. This value you are trying to parse to float. `Float.parseFloat(string)` will throw a NumberFormatException if the String is not a numeric. In `parseFloat()` method, the string parameter will be converted to a primitive float value.

You can check the value entered is numeric or not and then parse it to float.

```
float rec1 = 0;

   if(isNumeric(receive)){
       rec1 = Float.parseFloat(receive);
       if(rec1 < total){

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Insufficient Amount");

       }
   }else {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter a Valid Amount");
            c.jTextField1.setText("");
         }
```

The method is

```
 public static boolean isNumeric(String s) {  
    return s.matches("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+");  
}
```

Comment: hey thank you about this it helped me to solve my problem but there is a small problem after it runs if i enter a letter it would display Enter a Valid Amount after you press okay then Insufficient Amount will pop up also how solve that? im sorry for the questions but im still learning about java thank you again in advance

Comment: Try the changed code. it was because the if(rec1 < total) check kept out

Comment: Hey it finally work but i forgot there is also else next after the last line but i already solved it :D very much appreciated your help